# TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timestr'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dateutil

I am trying to scrape a website, but I keep getting the error that is in the title of this post. I have not figured out a way to solve this issue, and would greatly appreciate any help.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
from dateutil.parser import parser

url = 'website url'
info = requests.get(url)
data = info.json()

for entry in data['properties']['periods']:
    t = entry['startTime']
    print(parser.parse(t))
```

The website that I am trying to scrape is a weather forecast API, in a JSON format. The `'properties'`, `'periods'` and `'startTime'` are categories in the JSON. The funny thing is that when I feed the parser the value that is stored in these categories, it works seamlessly, but not when the value is a variable. What am I doing wrong?

[Example Data](https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/TOP/31,80/forecast/hourly)

Comment: Are you sure that every `entry` in `data['properties']['periods]` exists? Or that it's always the same type of data? It would be nice if you could include the website url as well.

Comment: @chemicalwill, `data['properties']['periods']` is a big list of items. Each of these items becomes the `entry` when the for loop cycles. Inside the 'entry', the information is different because it is an hourly weather forecast.

Comment: I know. I'm saying I would suspect that at some point, you have an `entry` that is `None`, which is causing your error. That is, your entry is blank.

Comment: @chemicalwill, I opened the python3 terminal and imported the parser then ran: `parser.parse(data['properties']['periods'][0]['startTime'] and it worked. I don't understand how it works here but not in my program.

Comment: That only represents 1 `entry`. Like the other commenter, I think you will need to further validate that `entry` is always a `timestr`, else do something/pass/etc.

Comment: `if t is not None: print(parser.parse(t))   else: pass` does not work. Maybe there is something wrong with the format of `t`?

Comment: You're going to need to either post the website, the json data, or both. We can't guess at you're parsing.

Comment: I'm sorry, the website is specific to my location so I would rather not share it. The website with the exact same format but different information can be found here: [link](https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/TOP/31,80/forecast/hourly).

Comment: Be sure to link that example data in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`parser` is a class](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/parser/_parser.html#parser.parse):

> ```py
> class parser(object):
>    def __init__(self, info=None):
>        self.info = info or parserinfo()
>
>    def parse(self, timestr, default=None,
>              ignoretz=False, tzinfos=None, **kwargs):
>        [...]
> ```

When you do something like `parser.parse(t)` you are passing `t` as the **`self`** argument and the ***required*** positional argument `timestr` doesn't get a value. You need to call this method on an instance:

```
parser().parse(t)
```

And since you're using it in a loop, it would be better to create it once ***before*** the loop:

```py
date_parser = parser()
for entry in data['properties']['periods']:
    t = entry['startTime']
    print(date_parser.parse(t))
```